# Parse code within json (Python)

Tags: python, json, string, indices

I  have the following Code:

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import simplejson as json

print (json.dumps(getQuotes('FRA:BMW'), indent=2))
b=(json.dumps(getQuotes('FRA:BMW'), indent=2))
print(type(b))
a = json.loads((json.dumps(getQuotes('FRA:BMW'), indent=2)))
print(type(a))
```

---

This is what I get:

```
[
  {
    "LastTradePrice": "73.39",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "&#8364;73.39",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2016-05-13T19:57:30Z",
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "May 13, 7:57PM GMT+2",
    "ID": "10224532",
    "Index": "FRA",
    "StockSymbol": "BMW",
    "LastTradeTime": "7:57PM GMT+2"
  }
]
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
[{'LastTradePrice': '73.39', 'LastTradeWithCurrency': '&#8364;73.39', 'LastTradeDateTimeLong': 'May 13, 7:57PM GMT+2', 'LastTradeDateTime': '2016-05-13T19:57:30Z', 'ID': '10224532', 'Index': 'FRA', 'StockSymbol': 'BMW', 'LastTradeTime': '7:57PM GMT+2'}]
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 11, in <module>
    print((a)["Index"])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

---

As you see I am not able to print the "Index" Value (in that case:FRA) (last code line of the script) No idea how that could work.

Comment: You don't need to surround your variables in parenthesis. `b=json.dumps(getQuotes('FRA:BMW'), indent=2)` would work, but the error says you can't access a list (something in the form of `[data]`) with a string like `a["index"]`. You could try `a[0]["Index"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `json` module to read that data. It is already a Python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The error said you have to index the list that `getQuotes` returns. Since there is only one element, you can use `[0]`

```
>>> from googlefinance import getQuotes
>>> fra_bmw = getQuotes('FRA:BMW')
>>> fra_bmw[0]["Index"]
u'FRA'
```